# divide columns using pattern in colnames

Tags: r

Assuming I have the following simplified table which has dynamic columns a_x (where x is an index e.g 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...) and b_x respectively. The number of `a` columns is always equal to the number of `b` columns but the total number of columns can be dynamic (not always 3 `a` and 3 `b`).
To make it clearer the following example depicts the structure of my data:

```
> d <- read.table(text = "10 20 25 0.3 0.23 0.34 
                          40 20 30 0.25 0.4 0.45")
> names(d) <- c("a_0", "a_1", "a_2", "b_0", "b_1", "b_2")
> d
   a_0 a_1 a_2  b_0  b_1  b_2
1  10  20  25   0.30 0.23 0.34
2  40  20  30   0.25 0.40 0.45
```

I would like to divide `a` columns with the corresponding `b` columns and save the results in new `c` columns. In order to do the divisions I use the transform() function (with hard-coded colnames) like this:

```
transform(d, c_0 = as.numeric(as.character(a_0)) / as.numeric(as.character(b_0)))
```

How can I do this step automatically using (probably) a pattern in colnames given the fact the number of columns of my input data is not always the same.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This escalated quickly :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are several approaches.  (1) and (1a) seem best but the others do show different approaches. They have the same column names and order as in the question except for (1a) and (2) but those could easily be fixed up if that were a problem.
No packages are used except for (4a).

**1) transform**

```
ix <- grep("a", names(d))
cbind(d, setNames(d[ix] / d[-ix], sub("a", "c", names(d)[ix])))
##   a_0 a_1 a_2  b_0  b_1  b_2       c_0      c_1      c_2
## 1  10  20  25 0.30 0.23 0.34  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
## 2  40  20  30 0.25 0.40 0.45 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

**1a)**  This is a variation of (1);

```
transform(d, c = setNames(d[ix], ix-1) / d[-ix])  # ix is from above
##   a_0 a_1 a_2  b_0  b_1  b_2       c.0      c.1      c.2
## 1  10  20  25 0.30 0.23 0.34  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
## 2  40  20  30 0.25 0.40 0.45 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

**2) reshape** Convert to long form, perform the division and convert back to wide form.

```
varying <- split(names(d), sub("_.*", "", names(d)))
long <- reshape(d, dir = "long", varying = varying, v.names = names(varying))
reshape(transform(long, c = a / b), dir = "wide", idvar = "id")[-1]
##     a.1  b.1       c.1 a.2  b.2      c.2 a.3  b.3      c.3
## 1.1  10 0.30  33.33333  20 0.23 86.95652  25 0.34 73.52941
## 2.1  40 0.25 160.00000  20 0.40 50.00000  30 0.45 66.66667
```

**3) apply** We can convert to a 3d array and then use `apply`.

```
nr <- nrow(d)
nc <- ncol(d)
cc <- apply(array(as.matrix(d), c(nr, nc / 2, 2)), 1:2, function(x) x[1] / x[2])
colnames(cc) <- paste("c", seq(0, length = ncol(cc)), sep = "_")
cbind(d, cc)
##   a_0 a_1 a_2  b_0  b_1  b_2       c_0      c_1      c_2
## 1  10  20  25 0.30 0.23 0.34  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
## 2  40  20  30 0.25 0.40 0.45 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

**4) diff**  Transpose the log of `d`, take diffs and reverse the log transpose by taking exp transpose. Then cbind it to `d`.  This solution assumes that all entries are strictly positive (which is the case in the question) so that we can take logs.

```
nc <- ncol(d)
cc <- t(exp(-diff(t(log(d)), nc/2)))
colnames(cc) <- paste("c", seq(0, length = ncol(cc)), sep = "_")
cbind(d, cc)
##   a_0 a_1 a_2  b_0  b_1  b_2       c_0      c_1      c_2
## 1  10  20  25 0.30 0.23 0.34  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
## 2  40  20  30 0.25 0.40 0.45 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

**(4a)** `diff.zoo` supports a geometric diff which performs a division rather than subtraction.  (In the current version of zoo `diff.zoo` requires that the elements of the input be strictly positive but this restriction is lifted in the development version of zoo.)

```
library(zoo)

nc <- ncol(d)
cc <- 1 / t(diff(zoo(t(d)), nc/2, arith = FALSE))
colnames(cc) <- paste("c", seq(0, length = ncol(cc)), sep = "_")
cbind(d, cc)
##     a_0 a_1 a_2  b_0  b_1  b_2       c_0      c_1      c_2
## x.1  10  20  25 0.30 0.23 0.34  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
## x.2  40  20  30 0.25 0.40 0.45 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

Answer (score 2):

We can remove everything after underscore from the names, split them and divide one-by-one, i.e.

```
Reduce(`/`, split.default(d, gsub('_.*', '', names(d))))
#        a_0      a_1      a_2
#1  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
#2 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `grep` to find "a" and "b" columns, and add the result as a matrix with nice `setNames` in your `transform`.

```
transform(d, ind=setNames(d[, grep("a", names(d))] / d[, grep("b", names(d))], 
                          gsub(".*(\\D)", "", grep("a", names(d), value=T))))
#   a_0 a_1 a_2  b_0  b_1  b_2     ind.0    ind.1    ind.2
# 1  10  20  25 0.30 0.23 0.34  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
# 2  40  20  30 0.25 0.40 0.45 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

Answer (score 1):

One option involving `dplyr` could be:

```
rename_all(select(d, starts_with("a"))/select(d, -starts_with("a")), 
           ~ paste("c", 1:(ncol(d)/2), sep = "_"))

        c_1      c_2      c_3
1  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
2 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `a` or `b` from the names with `sub` to get all indices and get the columns by using `paste0`. There is *no need that the columns are sorted.*

```
x <- substring(grep("^a_\\d+$", names(d), value = TRUE), 2)
cbind(d, setNames(d[paste0("a",x)] / d[paste0("b",x)], paste0("c",x)))
#  a_0 a_1 a_2  b_0  b_1  b_2       c_0      c_1      c_2
#1  10  20  25 0.30 0.23 0.34  33.33333 86.95652 73.52941
#2  40  20  30 0.25 0.40 0.45 160.00000 50.00000 66.66667
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr` actually has a really great new function for this. It is called `pivot_longer` which is a more sophisticated version of the `gather` function

```
d$id <- 1:nrow(d)
d.new <- d %>% pivot_longer(a_0:b_2, #what to pivot
               names_to = c(".value", "index"), #how names will change
               names_pattern = "(.)_(.)") #where to match names_to in the column names
d.new
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id index     a     b
  <int> <chr> <int> <dbl>
1     1 0        10  0.3 
2     1 1        20  0.23
3     1 2        25  0.34
4     2 0        40  0.25
5     2 1        20  0.4 
6     2 2        30  0.45
```

from here you are a simple mutate away from doing what you want

```
d.new <- d.new %>%
    mutate(c = a/b)
```

There is also a sister function called `pivot_wider` which could also transform the values back to what they were.

```
d <- d.new %>%
    pivot_wider(everything(), names_from = c(index), values_from = c(a,b,c))
d
# A tibble: 2 x 10
     id   a_0   a_1   a_2   b_0   b_1   b_2   c_0   c_1   c_2
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10    20    25  0.3   0.23  0.34  33.3  87.0  73.5
2     2    40    20    30  0.25  0.4   0.45 160    50    66.7
```

The id column was thrown in so that `pivot_wider` doesn't get confused on how to separate the row values. Both of these functions use tidyselection so if you didn't know how many indexes were in the column instead of saying 
`pivot_longer(a_0:b_2,`
you could say `pivot_longer(-id` and all columns except for `id` will be used in the `pivot_longer` function.